# can not run .mxml code

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a following .mxml code which doesn't run and gives an error directory/flexcode.html file not found.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                creationComplete="onLoad(event)" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private function onLoad(event:Event):void
            {
                Alert.show("Hello");
            }   
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: I am using flexbuilder to create and run the code.

Comment: I guess then it's more of a flexbuilder config issue as your MXML doesn't mention flexcode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple suggestions here for debugging:

1) Create a new project. Perhaps something in your project is corrupted.

2) Create a new workspace.  This is probably not the issue, but sometimes workspaces get corrupted, especially when upgrading Flex/Flashbuilder.

3) Ensure you're using an updated version of FLex-builder, now called Flashbuilder. Flashbuilder 4.5 is quite stable, from my experience.